# Easy way to access stateless session beans in EL?

Tags: java, jsf, ejb, el

Is there any possibility in EL to invoke a method of a stateless session bean without wrapping in a backing bean? Wrapping the method call in a backing bean produces redundant code and makes performing BU cumbersome as one has to wrap every single method.

Comment: What about annotating the bean `@Named` to make it accessible over EL?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can just annotate it with CDI's `@Named`.

E.g.

```
@Named
@Stateless
public class FooService {
    // ...
}
```

The properness of the design is questionable. It's IMHO tight coupling. I'd use this approach at most for extremely small webapps or quick prototyping.